# Android: Why wont this code let me set text (float?)?

Tags: android, floating-point, textview, sharedpreferences

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("cars4sale",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor GPS = settings.edit();
    GPS.putFloat("latitude", (float)location.getLatitude());
    GPS.putFloat("longitude", (float)location.getLongitude());
    GPS.commit();

    TextView GPSTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.GPSTV);
    SharedPreferences coords = getSharedPreferences("cars4sale",0);
    String gpsstr = GPS.getFloat("gps", "");    
    GPSTV.setText(gpsstr);
```

The main problem is eclipse wants me to change getFloat to putFloat and then when I do that it wants me to do getInt and then goes in a loop between float and Int. I just want to store a number to a textview field!

Comment: What exactly is happening for you? Are you getting an exception, is the TextView empty, etc.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of code that doesn't matter much, your layout is a bit funky (i'll clean it up some) and please provide a real error: when does what happen, and who doesn't let you do what and why? nevertheless, i'll guess your problem below ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because coords is a `sharedpreferences`, and I don't think you want to setText there?

Don't you mean

```
GPSTV.setText(gpsstr);
```

This:

```
String gpsstr = GPS.getFloat("gps", "");
```

Doesn't work, because `GPS` is your Editor, not your `sharedpreferences`. You need this

```
String gpsstr = String.valueOf(coords.getFloat("gps", 0));    
GPSTV.setText(gpsstr);
```

Comment: Yes. Good catch, sorry typo :). But the main problem still persists: it wants me to change getFloat to putFloat and then when I do that it wants me to do getInt and then goes in a loop between float and Int. No idea why

Comment: Haha, that wasn't there before :) .. I'll have a look :)

Comment: thanks!  I can give you the full function if need too, its just a button